# What happens if the static class Load fails

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Lets say the type `static class MyClass` fails to load during [AppDomain.AssemblyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Maybe the class contains a static property which reads the connection string from the config. Will further references to types in said DLL cause AppDomain.AssemblyLoad to attempt to re-load the DLL?

In other words, will AppDomain.AssemblyLoad retry a DLL that has previously failed to load?

Comment: Can you post some code as an example of what you mean?

Comment: Define "fails" in this case.  If it throws an exception then you'll likely see that exception from the class initializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so will it reload again for further calls on some methods on that class?

No. If type initialization fails for a particular type, that type is effectively useless throught the lifecycle of the AppDomain. Any further attempt to use the type will simply throw the same `TypeInitializationException` again immediately, without retrying. Avoid fallible type initialization wherever possible.

If you create a new AppDomain then *that* will try to initialize the type again.

Comment: I would add that if you try to reuse the same type later, the same exception will be thrown, without actually re-running the class initializer. (I've already seen funny things like TimeoutExceptions happening instantly... because of a failed WCF call in a class initializer. eurk)

Answer (score 0):

For sure not, if *design* of your class does not do that.

For example if for every method access you check either class was initialized or not, and if not initialize it, you *can* actually simulate that behavior.

But, to be honest, it's not so good design pattern.